# pip does not return control back to command prompt in windows

Tags: python, windows

I recently installed python 3.7 in windows. Whenever I install a module via pip, it doesn't return the control back to the command prompt. Example is given as follows

```
 pip install praw
Collecting praw
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/d7/0c7fb864ab9469f2964b2787910c78ade6d98c2d1710df1deab61beb99a1/praw-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 556kB/s
Collecting update-checker>=0.16 (from praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/c9/ab11855af164d03be0ff4fddd4c46a5bd44799a9ecc1770e01a669c21168/update_checker-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prawcore<2.0,>=1.0.0 (from praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/6d/4bf4d65d4771b15c70284c0626d24f230a5de6edac75c446fd22008ddbf6/prawcore-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.3.0 (from update-checker>=0.16->praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.5MB/s
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.3.0->update-checker>=0.16->praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 2.2MB/s
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.3.0->update-checker>=0.16->praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.3.0->update-checker>=0.16->praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.5MB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.3.0->update-checker>=0.16->praw)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (150kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 4.7MB/s
Installing collected packages: urllib3, chardet, idna, certifi, requests, update-checker, prawcore, praw
  The script chardetect.exe is installed in 'c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.7 praw-6.0.0 prawcore-1.0.0 requests-2.19.1 update-checker-0.16 urllib3-1.23
```

It just stops here. I have to press `CTRL+C` to exit. WHen I press `CTRL+C`, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\linklockfile.py", line 31, in acquire
    os.link(self.unique_name, self.lock_file)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\ragha\\AppData\\Local\\pip\\Cache\\DESKTOP-KKG32L1-54fc.16400-1747620134' -> 'C:\\Users\\ragha\\AppData\\Local\\pip\\Cache\\selfcheck.json.lock'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 246, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 265, in main
    pip_version_check(session, options)
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\outdated.py", line 140, in pip_version_check
    state.save(pypi_version, current_time)
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\outdated.py", line 70, in save
    with lockfile.LockFile(self.statefile_path):
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 197, in __enter__
    self.acquire()
  File "c:\users\ragha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\linklockfile.py", line 50, in acquire
    time.sleep(timeout is not None and timeout / 10 or 0.1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Does the newly installed package work?

Comment: Yes. After I exit using CTRL+C, the newly installed package works just fine.

Comment: At first glance it looks like a bug as pip is hanging on requiring a lock file.

Comment: @Sraw Yup. I just want to know how do I resolve this bug

Comment: I think manually delete that cache directory can solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a Python interpreter running in another window or in an IDE?

Comment: @abarnert No, I don't think so

Comment: Well, that rules out every idea I had (besides have you tried turning it off and on again, or reinstalling Python or pip from scratch… but don't do that—if it _does_ work, then you'll have no way to debug the problem, or figure out how to stop it from coming back again).

Comment: @abarnert Was in a bit of hurry. So I reinstalled Python completely :/ Works now.